# Problem with the Formal Definition of a Limit

Tags: calculus, limits, formal-proofs

Problem: Let $F$ and $G$ be functions such that $0\leq F(x)\leq G(x)$ for all $x$ near $c$, except possibly at $c$. Show that if $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} G(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} F(x)=0$.

I really don't know how to use the formal definition in this demonstration.

This is the solution but I can't understand
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdxTr.jpg)

Comment: What's the issue? What about it don't you understand?

Comment: the way the solution is proposed

Comment: That is too vague for anyone to help. Go look at the definition of a limit. This problem is the most direct application of the definition that I can imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what if what you mean is the Squeeze Theorem.
That is:
let F1, F2, G be functions such that
$$
F_1\left( x \right) \leqslant \,\,G\left( x \right) \leqslant F_2\left( x \right) 
$$

when x -> x0, lim F1 = lim F2 define = C
so that lim x -> x0 G = C

Comment: In your question, we can regard F1 as 0, that's it.